# Basic centering elements in adaptive row class in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

On my page I have lots of elements, which I need to show by several in a row in straight columns. Each element is an image of equal size. When you click on it, on it's place appears icon menu with three items in a row. All elements should be centred horizontally and vertically.

**There could be a different number of big images (6, 7, 8 or more) so I want to add them in one row-class.**

Now, I think I'm doing everything by bootstrap documentation, but elements logic on the page steel appears to be broken.

What am I doing wrong?

**[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWPOzo)**

```
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid wrapper">
    <div class="row center-block text-center">
      <div class="center-block col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
        <div class="row center-block">
          <div class="col-md-12 center-block">
            <img src="http://img.leprosorium.com/2474872">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="center-block col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
        <div class="row center-block">
          <div class="col-md-12 center-block">
            <img src="http://img.leprosorium.com/2474872">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="center-block col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
        <div class="row center-block">
          <div class="col-md-12 center-block">
            <img src="http://img.leprosorium.com/2474872">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="center-block col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
        <div class="row-fluid center-block text-center pagination-centered">
          <div class="col-md-4 center-block text-center pagination-centered link">
            <a target="_blank" href="#"><img src="http://img.leprosorium.com/2474848"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 center-block text-center pagination-centered link">
            <a target="_blank" href="#"><img src="http://img.leprosorium.com/2474848"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 center-block text-center pagination-centered link">
            <a target="_blank" href="#"><img src="http://img.leprosorium.com/2474848"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 center-block text-center pagination-centered link">
            <a target="_blank" href="#"><img src="http://img.leprosorium.com/2474848"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 center-block text-center pagination-centered link">
            <a target="_blank" href="#"><img src="http://img.leprosorium.com/2474848"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 center-block text-center pagination-centered link">
            <a target="_blank" href="#"><img src="http://img.leprosorium.com/2474848"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 center-block text-center pagination-centered link">
            <a target="_blank" href="#"><img src="http://img.leprosorium.com/2474848"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 center-block text-center pagination-centered link">
            <a target="_blank" href="#"><img src="http://img.leprosorium.com/2474848"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 center-block text-center pagination-centered link">
            <a target="_blank" href="#"><img src="http://img.leprosorium.com/2474848"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="center-block col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
        <div class="row center-block">
          <div class="col-md-12 center-block">
            <img src="http://img.leprosorium.com/2474872">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="center-block col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
        <div class="row center-block">
          <div class="col-md-12 center-block">
            <img src="http://img.leprosorium.com/2474872">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="center-block col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
        <div class="row center-block">
          <div class="col-md-12 center-block">
            <img src="http://img.leprosorium.com/2474872">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="center-block col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
        <div class="row center-block">
          <div class="col-md-12 center-block">
            <img src="http://img.leprosorium.com/2474872">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="center-block col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
        <div class="row center-block">
          <div class="col-md-12 center-block">
            <img src="http://img.leprosorium.com/2474872">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Screenshot of what I get:
[image]

Screenshot of what I need:
[image]

Please point me in the right direction. Thank you in advance. I was able to done it without bootstrap, b I hope it could be done only by the right usage of bootstrap and elements, because I want to save the adaptive layout.

**UPD** @LegendaryAks fixed the problem with gap by using `<div class="clearfix"></div>` after icons element, but problem of centering all elements for the adaptive layout and unknown number of total elements is still open.

**UPD2** Centering just one element in the end is not enough, because we need to know how to center from one to max number of elements on the last row, sow that we could load all the elements on a page with no worry for the last row centering.

Answer (score 3):

There you go i think this did the trick . You can check the demo at http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QybXQJ?editors=100

What i did is I added a div with class clearfix after the fourth div. I hope this is what you are looking for

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Comment: It did fixed the gap after icons, but there is still no centering for the big images - https://www.dropbox.com/s/wxk3au9g5lil5ld/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%202015-12-11%2014.22.54.png?dl=0

Comment: Code i have made to work till md grid. So please try resizing the codepen.

Comment: but this code won't work if there to elements on the last row, it's not adaptive

Comment: I think since you have taken col-md-3 for the last div i cannot even add offset make it center align. That is the reason i added custom class. Using bootstrap this difficult to achieve. We will need to add custom class to achieve it i guess. Hope it helps.

Comment: can we add a custom class to all of them, not just to the last one?

Answer (score 3):

there the solution using only css:

```
.center-block-big:nth-child(4n+1) {
  clear: left;
}
.center-block-big:last-child {
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: none;
}
```

the only thing is that in this example i have removed the col-lg-2 to apply it to all resolution, and edited the class name to only apply to the container of the big images and not the twitter ones.

updated [codepen](http://codepen.io/eparisio/pen/dGMYwG?editors=110)

---

If you want mantain the space on lg resolution you need to play with the col width a bit in this way:

updated [codepen](http://codepen.io/eparisio/pen/rxeOPb)

---

If you have dynamic elements you can use this to make that only if one element is on a row it will be centered:

```
.center-block-big:nth-child(4n+1) {
  clear: left;
}
.center-block-big:last-child:not(:nth-child(5n)) {
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: none;
}
.center-block-big:nth-child(4n+2),
.center-block-big:nth-child(4n+3),
.center-block-big:nth-child(4n) {
  float: left!important;
}
```

updated [codepen](http://codepen.io/eparisio/pen/rxeOPb), add .center-block-big elements to see the effect

Comment: But none of this examples will work if there would be two elements on the last rows, or three. So it's not really adaptive. But great work anyway! Thanks!

Comment: centering the last x element without having a sort of container is impossible with only css, you need to use javascript to archive what you want.
The last solution that i propose in any case center the last element if it's alone, it's the best solution without using js.

Answer (score 1):

use `col-md-12` instead of `col-md-6` at the last element of your design.
Try this:

```
<div class="col-md-12 center-block text-center pagination-centered link">
    <a target="_blank" href="#">VK</a>
</div>
```

AND

```
<div class="col-md-12 center-block text-center pagination-centered link">
    <a target="_blank" href="#">FB</a>
</div>
```

for vertical align use make a new class

```
.verticalcenter {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
}
```

and use it.
make your HTML structure like below:

```
First Row..
<div class="row center-block text-center">
    <div class="center-block col-md-4">
    </div>
    <div class="center-block col-md-4">
    </div>
    <div class="center-block col-md-4">
    </div>
</div>
Second Row..
<div class="row center-block text-center">
    <div class="center-block col-md-4">
    </div>
    <div class="center-block col-md-4">
    </div>
    <div class="center-block col-md-4">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't do this, because there always can be different number of elements on the page and I don't know which would be the last one (and images, annd menu).

Comment: And how do I center text elements vertically?

Comment: can you give them en extra cs apart from bootstrap

Comment: Sure, that would be no problem

Comment: If i'm using your vericalcenter setting, i'm loosing the two elements in a row logic for text menu. Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWPOzo?editors=110#0 Screenshot https://www.dropbox.com/s/wvfw9fkumlzuzkv/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%202015-12-09%2013.55.55.png?dl=0

Comment: I can't add rows for each row because elements are dynamically added and I want to use .col-sm- and .col-xs- in later development for that elements. I think it should be a matter of min height or somehing

Comment: yes but when your element are more your min height is not helping

Comment: try min height and max height both then it should help.
or when you make it dynamic then by coding logic you can make structure that i will shown you in answer.
and that was fully responsive.

Comment: `min-height: 100px;
max-height: 200px;`

Comment: I understand this solution, but row div for each row would be excessive, becaouse I need adaptive layout

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97457/discussion-between-maay-and-ajay-makwana).